# Geometric sequence , how to find common ratio

Tags: probability

The first term of a `Geometric sequence` is `25` and the fourth term is `1`.

How do you find the `common ratio`?

I am able to find the `common ratio` if the first 3 terms are given.

Comment: i dont know why i treated it like a arithmetic sequence where 
a5-a1 = 4r

4r= (25-1)

4r=24

r=24/4

@DhanukaLakshan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let a1 = 25,
 a4 = a*r^3 = 1

a4 / a1 => r^3  = 1/25

r = Cube root of (1/25).

Three terms not needed. Hope it will solve!!

Comment: thanks man i looked at a lot of examples on the net and all of the examples had already given the first five sequences .

this helped me alot 
cheers